# How can I make an autorun to make a program open a file automatically

Tags: autorun

I have a media player that plays a certain file and I need to have both in an exe archive so that when I click the exe, it start playing the file using that player automatically.
it's like the file is already embedded in that player.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMS has an mp3player template that does the job and finally exports everything in an autorun exe neat and clean.

> > Off-Road:
> >     "I got no idea who was that stupid guy that gave my question a minus vote.
> >     to that stupid guy: this question has never been asked anywhere else and it's totally clear and useful for those who'd need it. Though I'm a new user, I've been usin Stackoverflow tips for a long time. the reason why I registered was because I couldn't find the answer anywhere else. If you don't wanna help no need to roam around like a gadfly :| no offense to the editor though!"